# Sectioning off commented section with curly brackets (code blocks)

Tags: java, scope, comments, documentation

I want to maximize readability in my own project, and have come up with a method I haven't seen used anywhere else.
My question is if there are any negative consequences to this approach.

In the following code, I am using code blocks not for scope reasons, but to have a nice way to put a "comment header" on top.

```
this.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));
this.setSpacing(5);
this.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);

// top bar (left  pane, title, right  pane)
{
    label_enterKey.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    label_enterKey.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
    label_enterKey.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_CENTER);

    .....

    this.getChildren().add(hbox_topBar);
}

// center part ( input text field, messages)
{
    textfield_keyEntry.setOnAction((event) -> finalizeEntry(event));
   
    ...
}

// bottom bar (back button, proceed button)
{
    button_proceed.setOnAction((event) -> finalizeEntry(event));

    ....

    this.getChildren().add(hbox_buttons);
}
```

Comment: It is possible do it this way. But my approach would be to put these code blocks in separate methods with good names and call them.

Comment: @RalfRenz yeah you're right maybe that's better